# Debug JS Verticle vertx

Tags: vert.x, intellij-14, vertx-verticle

Is there a way to debug a javascript verticle in intellij(or any other app/tool) like you can debug it on any browser dev tool? I have tried adding *debugger* to the code but doesn't work and I could literally find nothing online on this.

Comment: If you are able to run the app in IntelliJ, just run it in "debug mode" and put a break-point whenever you would like to "stop".

Comment: It wouldn't let me put break point on a .js file

Comment: Can you share the code or a project in Git?

Comment: if you are able to run the application in intelliJ, it will allow you to debug.

Comment: Thats the thing, I can't put a breakpoint on a .js like I can on a java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug from IntelliJ IDEA. I'm currently on version (2017.2.4) and this is how it works. Assuming you have a minimal js project (for reference I've used this generator: http://vertx-starter.jetdrone.xyz/)

I've added 2 breakpoints to the generated main_verticle.js file:

[image: add breakpoint]

Now you need to configure your runner, for this you need to create a run configuration of type `Application` with the following config:

[image]

- `Main Class`: **always** `io.vertx.core.Launcher`
- `Program Arguments`: `run` your_js_file.js

You can test the configuration by running it and see that the server starts.
Now to debug just press the debug icon and you should get:

[image: debug session]

Comment: Thats the problem, I have 2017.2.6, just updated from 2017.2.4 this morning, and I cant even add breakpoint to a .js file. http://ohmygawd.azurewebsites.net/statics/DebugProb.png
http://ohmygawd.azurewebsites.net/statics/vertxdebugging.mp4

Comment: Are you using the ultimate version? I guess the community version doesn't support javascript debugging.